# Fatal: Unable to checkout working tree

Tags: github-for-windows

I am cloning the master branch from a GitHub repo onto my system. It throws this error:

> Checking connectivity ...done eate file Icon fatal:
>   unable to checkout working tree warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout
>   failed.

I've tried to include the suggestions for line ending problems in Windows as [the help doc suggests](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings)
but still I am facing the same issue.

How can this be solved?

- Windows 7

Answer (score 12):

As I know of, you will want to modify any file names containing: \, /, :, *, ?, ", <, >, or |, as Windows does not comply with those symbols for file naming purposes.

A nice and simple "fix" would be to download the files as a zip archive (which is supported by github), then modify the troublesome file names in File Explorer and then, finally, extract the zip archive in your desired directory.

Answer (score 2):

Some documents in the file name under Windows is illegal. Delete these files to, or use OS X to modify the file name and then clone under Windows.

[Git can't checkout a repo from github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20715804/)

Answer (score 2):

Check the error messages carefully. Some file names might be long or some other issues will be there concerning a file. Or maybe there is not enough space. But do git clone on command prompt and go through the last couple of error messages

Answer (score 1):

I got this error trying to download some repos with blacklisted windows filenames:

`error: invalid path 'drivers/gpu/drm/nouveau/nvkm/subdev/i2c/aux.c'` notice the file is called `aux.c` which is a banned word in windows because AUX is a namespace for auxiliary port connections. Backwards compatibility to the stone ages basically.

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file?redirectedfrom=MSDN#win32-device-namespaces

For a full list of reserved keywords see second-last dotpoint: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file?redirectedfrom=MSDN#naming-conventions

Answer (score 1):

Check the error messages carefully. Some file names might be long or some other issues will be there concerning a file.

```
PS> git clone https://github.com/jonathanbaraldi/devops-ninja-multicloud-multicluster-pt.git
Cloning into 'devops-ninja-multicloud-multicluster-pt'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 1951, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (1951/1951), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1494/1494), done.
remote: Total 1951 (delta 377), reused 1934 (delta 364), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (1951/1951), 6.40 MiB | 19.91 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (377/377), done.

> error: invalid path 'doc/logos/1*afkK1deEdJkuN3IhnzuzKg.png'
> 
> fatal: unable to checkout working tree

warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry with 'git restore --source=HEAD :/'

PS> git status
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
PS> cd .\devops-ninja-multicloud-multicluster-pt\
PS> git status
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        deleted:    .gitignore
        deleted:    LICENSE
        deleted:    README.md
        deleted:    app/api-book/Dockerfile
```

More info:
https://www.unidadvirtual.com/problema-al-clonar-un-proyecto-con-git-en-windows-error-filename-too-long

Answer (score 1):

My case-specific issue was that someone on my team created a bunch of folders with a space at the end of the name.(e.g. 'my_folder ', with the path looking like 'my_folder2/my_folder /document.pdf')

This seems to be possible on Mac, but Windows doesn't allow spaces at the end of folder names. Removing those spaces solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me when the path to clone was long. Later, I have downloaded it to a location with a very short folder name and it worked.
Error occurred when clone location was: c://Users//Source/Repo/
Error didn't occur when I changed the clone location to C://Repo/